# Error CS0120 with FindViewById in Xamarin/Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have this Error with FindViewbyId Under Xamarin/Android: 
*Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the property , method, or the non-static field '* .
Here is my axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutDeadReckoning"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff66ff66"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="startx"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my code

```
public class DeadReckoningActivity : Activity
    {//Declaration             
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_dead_reckoning);

            int method = Intent.GetIntExtra(KEY_RECKONING_METHOD, METHOD_DEAD_RECKONING);

            mDeadReckoning = new DeadReckoning(this);  //Class

             intent = new Intent(this, typeof( BroadcastService) ); // public   class BroadcastService : Service
        }

        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
        private class broadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                updateUI(intent);
            }
            private void updateUI(Intent intent)
            {
                float mstartx = mDeadReckoning.getmStartX();

                 TextView startx =FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.startx);

                   startx.SetText(Convert.ToChar(mstartx));

            }           
        }      
    }
```

Can you see what is going wrong?

Comment: Any example of the code you're using to get the view?

Comment: Where are you defining your `broadcastReceiver` class? Is it inside the `Activity` class that is using your aforementioned layout? If possible, can you share the complete code of your `Activity`?

Comment: Here is the code of my Activity